# -1/0/1 comparators vs bool comparators, what difference does it make?

Tags: comparison, comparator

Some languages have comparators that return `-1`, `0` or `1` and others have comparators that just return a boolean, i.e. `0` or `1`.

A `-1, 0, 1` comparator has to do 1-2 checks (and 1-2 checks in the calling function as well), while a boolean comparator always has to do just one. Instead, the calling function might have to call the boolean comparator twice.

It seems like a boolean comparator is always better, i.e. faster and easier to implement.

Does a `-1, 0, 1` comparator function have any benefit over the boolean counterpart?

Comment: A common use case for a -1, 0, 1 comparator is in sorting functions. Even if, internally, it's just a series of Boolean comparisons, at the very least it's more meaningful than a single Boolean comparison (which at best can only tell you whether or not two values are equal - whether the values are numbers, strings or other Booleans).

Comment: but two calls to a boolean function gives the same information, right? I mean, C++ uses a single boolean comparator when sorting.

Comment: I'd rather not to seek some conspiracy here, it is just two different approaches. Boolean comparator is usually easier to implement, additional check in int comparator often costs less CPU time than calling a function for a second time (one or two conditional jumps vs maintaining stack and args).

Comment: That could be an answer, @Alex. If you can't inline, the function call overhead is significant.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the -1/0/1 comparison is for sorting.

-1 (technically it could be any negative number) is returned if `this` is less than `that`.

0 is returned if `this` is equal to `that`.

1 (or any positive number) is returned if `this` is greater than `that`.

This allows `this` to be placed relative to `that` with only one comparison call. Any call returning boolean would require two calls.

Comment: yes, but you still need two internal checks in the comparator function to decide what to return?

Comment: That is correct. It doesn't change the amount of work, it just moves it to an encapsulated function. Although if function calls are expensive, the net cost may still be lower.